# Not able to call multiple get methods properly

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I Have The Following Get Methods In Web api AgentApiController

```
    public IHttpActionResult Get()      
    public IHttpActionResult Get(string agentid)                
    public TennetDetails getTenantDetail(string tenantid)        
    public IHttpActionResult getAgentByNumber(string mobile)        
    private Agent GetAgentDetail(PartyQuery query)        
    public IHttpActionResult GetDigiAgentDetail(int agentid)        
    public IHttpActionResult GetDigiAgentHistory(int agentid)
```

When I call AgentApi/Get/7 , `public IHttpActionResult Get()` is fires .actually i need to fire `IHttpActionResult Get(string agentid)`.

when i delete the `public IHttpActionResult Get()` method and call  `public IHttpActionResult Get()` then 
        `public IHttpActionResult GetDigiAgentHistory(int agentid)` fires

i have changed tyhe route in WebApiConfig as bellow

`

```
      config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithId", "Api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }, new { id = @"\d+" });

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithAction", "Api/{controller}/{action}");

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiGet", "Api/{controller}", new { action = "Get" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) });

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiPost", "Api/{controller}", new { action = "Post" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Post) });

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithActionWithId", "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

`

but i am still not able to find solution for the problem

Comment: The routes are matched with the order they are defined. When there is a match, it won't check the remaining, and method overloading will not work in the same way it works for normal methods. The best way is to use the route attribute and explicitly specify different routing for each API methods.

Comment: thank you for answer,but i had some other problem in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my code there was some problem

I changed the

`public IHttpActionResult Get(string agentid)`

to

`public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)`

now the code is working fine.

I think since i mention id(parameter name) in the route,

`config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithId", "Api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }, new { id = @"\d+" });`

I should use id itself as name of  parameter for actions.